# bijection from $\mathbb{Q} - \{a\}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ using elementary functions only?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, field-theory, elementary-functions

I was wondering, can you define a bijection from $\mathbb{Q} - \{a\}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ using elementary functions only ($a \in \mathbb{Q}$)?

Of course there are many set theoretic bijections like that, but I'm looking for a constructive one, a formula, using elementary functions, a smile and a hug if you can do it using field operations only.

Edit:
- Elementary functions are field operations, exponentials, logarithms, constants, roots and such.
- You may give piecewise functions, but only a finite number of convex pieces.

Comment: Which functions do you include as elementary?

Comment: No need for vague tags. Less so as the tags you used actually are *not* vague, but precise terms for totally unrelated things.

Comment: Take a sequence  $(x_n)\subset \Bbb Q$ and $x_n\to a$ . For $x\neq a$ you can have $f(x)=x$.

Comment: @Dimitris I don't really see what you mean by that.

Comment: I doubt you can do this with elementary functions.  Among the elementary functions the only ones which obviously send rational numbers to rational numbers are rational functions with rational coefficients, and the only function of this form which has much of a chance is $f(x) = \frac{cx + d}{x - a}$.  But this doesn't work because it misses the rational number $c$.  None of this is a proof, but it makes me skeptical.

Answer (score 3):

If $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ it's easy! In any other case Consider the following $f:\mathbb{Q}-\{\alpha\}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$

$ f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         x & \mbox{if $x \notin\mathbb{N}$}\\
        \alpha & \mbox{if $x = 0$}\\
         x-1 & x\in\mathbb{N}^*     \end{array} \right. $

Comment: What is $\mathbb{N}^*$?

Comment: I'm quite certain that OP was not looking for piecewise functions.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}^*=\mathbb{N}-{0}$

Comment: Thank you for the function, but yes, as stated by @Lord_Farin, I'm not looking for piecewise functions (actually, a finite number of convex pieces will be okay)